# Optimizing performance of a selectable list items with a closure

Tags: reactjs

I made a multi selectable list and have been trying to improve its re-rendering performance. The below code shows what I made (in my actual project, a list is much longer).
Currently, when I click a list item, it re-renders every row. I want to render only a clicked row. It seems it is possible with React.memo, React.useCallback, but I haven't succeeded to use them properly for this use cases. Any feedback is welcomed! Thanks in advance.

```html
<div id="app" />
```

```
const animals = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Fish']

interface AnimalProps {
  selected: boolean;
  name: string;
  onClick: (name: string) => void;
}
const Animal = ({selected, name, onClick}: AnimalProps) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}>{`[${selected ? 'X' : ' '}]`} {name}</div>
)

const useFilter = (initialValue: string[]) => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState<string[]>(initialValue)
  const makeOnClick  = (item: string) => () => {
    const ix = items.indexOf(item)
    const newItems = (ix > -1) ?
      [...items.slice(0, ix), ...items.slice(ix + 1)]
      :
      [...items, item]
    setItems(newItems)
  }
  const isSelected = (item: string) => items.indexOf(item) > -1
  return { items, makeOnClick, isSelected };
 }

const App = () => {
  const {items, makeOnClick, isSelected} = useFilter([])
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {animals.map(i => (
          <Animal name={i} selected={isSelected(i)} onClick={makeOnClick(i)} key={i} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div>Selected: {items.join(', ')}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
```

Comment: what's the actual length of list ?

Comment: lol that's quite short I have to face a similar problem but my data is 40k plus to render in the dropdown. the below solution didn't work for yaa ?

Comment: Yes! My list's row has inner component deeply and it has `<input type="text ...>` and wanted to optimize (My demo in a question is rather simplified). 40k is too long. Why do you need so long list

Comment: zip codes the thing is called zip codes.

Comment: For a 40k items list, preventing some unnecessary renders is probably not enough. I think what you need is virtual scroll. You can try this library: https://react-virtual.tanstack.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we already knew that our goal is to prevent Animal from unnecessary renders. Let's just add the `React.memo` to it:

```js
const Animal = React.memo(({selected, name, onClick}: AnimalProps) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}>{`[${selected ? 'X' : ' '}]`} {name}</div>
))
```

Of course it's not doing anything now. We can clearly see that `name` and `selected` are static values. They are just string and boolean, so they should be able to work with `React.memo` well. The problem is the `onClick`.

In this code we can see that we are creating new functions in the loop:

```js
const makeOnClick  = (item: string) => () => {
  // ...
}
makeOnClick(i)
```

On every single render, the generated function is always a different one. The current code is similar to:

```
<Animal onClick={() => onClick(i)} />
```

This will never work with React.memo, because it's always creating a new function. So our goal is to pass a static function to it. Let's just modify it to:

```js
<Animal onClick={onClick} />
```

But we still need to know the `i`. So in the Animal component, we can do this:

```js
const Animal = React.memo(({ selected, name, onClick }: AnimalProps) => (
  <div onClick={() => onClick(name)}>
    {`[${selected ? 'X' : ' '}]`} {name}
  </div>
));
```

In this case, if `onClick` is a static value then the Animal component won't do unnecessary renders. So our final goal is to create a static onClick function for the Animal.

Also the `makeOnClick` is no longer a `makeOnClick` now. We are not going to need a function that returns a function, so let's just name it `onClick` and remove the extra inner function:

```
const onClick  = (item: string) => {
  const ix = items.indexOf(item)
  const newItems = (ix > -1) ?
    [...items.slice(0, ix), ...items.slice(ix + 1)]
    :
    [...items, item]
  setItems(newItems)
}
```

Now the last step. We only need to memoize this function, but we can see that it needs the latest `items`. In other words, the `items` is its dependency. So even if we add `useCallback` now, we still need to add the `items` to the dependencies. And we know that `items` changes when an item is selected, `useCallback` won't help anything. We have to somehow remove `items` from the dependencies.

Luckily, `setState` actually supports a callback function. For exmaple:

```js
setItems(items => [...items, 'foo'])
```

Which means, we can access to the current `items`, without having `items` a dependency. So we only need to change the `setItems` to use an update function:

```js
const onClick = React.useCallback((item: string) => {
  setItems((items) => {
    const ix = items.indexOf(item);
    const newItems =
      ix > -1
        ? [...items.slice(0, ix), ...items.slice(ix + 1)]
        : [...items, item];
    return newItems;
  });
}, []);
```

It should be working now. See the full working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-foxpnu?file=index.tsx

You can inspect the renders by using React Developer Tools, or just add some conosle.log to the Animal component.